# Why does this jQuery tabbedDialog plugin only work in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I [found this jQuery code](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/combining-ui-dialog-and-tabs) to create a tabbed dialog:

```
$('#tenant').tabbedDialog();

$.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {
    this.tabs();
    this.dialog({'modal':true,'width':800, 'height':600,'minWidth':400, 'minHeight':300,'draggable':true});
    this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').append($('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'));
    this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').css({'position':'absolute','right':'0', 'top':'23px'});
    this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close > a').css({'float':'none','padding':'0'});
    var tabul = this.find('ul:first');
    this.parent().addClass('ui-tabs').prepend(tabul).draggable('option','handle',tabul); 
    this.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
    tabul.addClass('ui-dialog-titlebar');
}

<div id="tenant">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tenant_details">My Tenant</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tenant_events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tenant_jobs">Jobs</a></li>
            <li class="ui-tab-dialog-close"></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div id="tenant_details">
                some details
            </div>
            <div id="tenant_events">
                some events
            </div>
            <div id="tenant_jobs">
                some jobs
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it only seems to work in Firefox.

I tested it in Chrome 8 (displays nothing) and IE8 (shows tab content on main page) and it doesn't work properly in either.

Any guesses why not?

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/LqVcX/)

Comment: Just for reference, that's really not the recommended format for jQuery plugins these days - [this is](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Summary_and_Best_Practices).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to troubleshoot this old code, try using this, which I've personally used: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/